# Endless loop with For..Next statement

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Objective: Develop a Macro whereby I select in sheet1, divide the values in every twelfth row by 1.35 and transfer them into a selected range of cells in sheet2.

I started simple and it worked:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(114, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(58, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(115, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(70, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(116, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(82, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(117, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(94, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(118, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(106, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(119, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(118, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(120, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(130, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(121, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(142, 14) / 1.35
```

I then wanted to breakdown the code by using a loop, but cannot get it right.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Do
i = 12
j = 14
For l = 114 To 121
For k = 58 To 142 Step 12
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(l, i).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, j) / 1.35
Next k
Next l
Loop Until l = 121
```

My ultimate goal is to repeat this loop across different columns as the data comes in.

Comment: Instead of an inner loop (the `for k`), maybe do k=k+12?

Comment: let me confirm, what you want to insert to cells from Sheet2, value or formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would use index to do this `=INDEX(Sheet1!$N$58:$N$142,(ROWS($A$114:$A114)-1)*12)/1.35` please make N the column that you are trying to divide just put this in the cells that you are trying to populate in sheet2

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to take out the "do - loop L ". That is causing the infinite loop, as you are never increasing "L". (the for loop which uses the same named variable, has the variable only within his own scope... then it won't be infinite anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow:

```
Dim k, l As Integer

'Set before row
k = 46

For l = 114 To 121 Step 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(l, 12) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k + 12, 14) / 1.35
Next l
```

I am not clear with your requirement, means, don't know what you want to insert (formula or value).

**if you want to set formula to Sheet2's cells**, modify the setting line as follow:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(l, 12).Formula  = "=" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k + 12, 14).Address & "/1.35"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub Temp2()
    Dim X As Long, ReadCol As Long, UpdateCode As Long
    ReadCol = 14
    UpdateCol = 12
    For X = 114 To 121
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, UpdateCol).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(58 + ((X - 114) * 12), ReadCol) / 1.35
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't have any sample data to test so here is a debug version that will output to the immediate window (CTRL-G) what the complete line compiles to:

```
Sub Temp2()
    Dim X As Long, ReadCol As Long, UpdateCode As Long
    ReadCol = 14
    UpdateCol = 12
    For X = 114 To 121
        Debug.Print "Worksheets(""Sheet2"").Cells(" & X & ", " & UpdateCol & ").Formula = Worksheets(""Sheet1"").Cells(" & 58 + ((X - 114) * 12) & ", " & ReadCol & ") / 1.35"
    Next
End Sub
```

results:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(114, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(58, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(115, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(70, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(116, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(82, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(117, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(94, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(118, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(106, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(119, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(118, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(120, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(130, 14) / 1.35
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(121, 12).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(142, 14) / 1.35
```